# Selected Item has to be added to cart in android

Tags: android

Already I have some static data in expanded list view and from that list if any customer click on that multiple items they has to be selected and it has to be added into cart.So for that please give me some suggestions and if u have any implemented code please post here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create hash map for your cart data

Comment: and then after that can u pls give 4 me a clear brief answer

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Use_MVC_Pattern_To_Create_Very_Basic_Shopping_Cart__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=116

Answer (score 1):

Assume there is two button for add and remove item on cart screen so both have click event on adapter class below is just sample example

```
holder.imgAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mCartDetail mCartDetail;
                    if (Utility.mCartList.containsKey(mcategoryProductDetail.productdetails.get(0).psid)) {
                        mCartDetail = Utility.mCartList.get(mcategoryProductDetail.productdetails.get(0).psid);
                        int finalMmaxBuy = 0;
                        if (!mCartDetail.categoryProductDetail.max_buy_qty.equalsIgnoreCase(" ")) {
                            finalMmaxBuy = Integer.parseInt(mCartDetail.categoryProductDetail.max_buy_qty);
                        }
                        if (mCartDetail.addQuantity < finalMmaxBuy) {
                            mCartDetail.addQuantity++;
                        } 
                    } else {
                        mCartDetail = new mCartDetail();
                        mCartDetail.categoryProductDetail = mcategoryProductDetail.productdetails.get(0);
                        mCartDetail.addQuantity = 1;
                        Utility.mCartList.put(mcategoryProductDetail.productdetails.get(0).psid, mCartDetail);
                    }

                    mCartDetail.totalprice = Float.parseFloat(mCartDetail.categoryProductDetail.our_price) * mCartDetail.addQuantity;


                    holder1.tvProductCounter.setText(String.valueOf(mCartDetail.addQuantity));
                }
            });

            holder.imgRemoveItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (Utility.mCartList.containsKey(mcategoryProductDetail.productdetails.get(0).psid)) {
                        mCartDetail mCartDetail = Utility.mCartList.get(mcategoryProductDetail.productdetails.get(0).psid);

                        mCartDetail.addQuantity--;
                        mCartDetail.totalprice = Float.parseFloat(mCartDetail.categoryProductDetail.our_price) * mCartDetail.addQuantity;

                        holder1.tvProductCounter.setText(String.valueOf(mCartDetail.addQuantity));
                        if (mCartDetail.addQuantity == 0) {
                            Utility.mCartList.remove(mCartDetail.categoryProductDetail.psid);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }


                }
            });
```

and below is my model class and hashmap for data storing and send to server

```
public static HashMap<String, CartDetail> mCartList;
public CartDetail mCartDetail;
```

Hope this concept will help you to implement in your scenario

Comment: Ajay I vl post my code can u pls suggest for that or else pls give me ur mail id. dont take me wrong I have doubt in that thats y